# Range loop on a Go channel and garbage collection of the loop variable

Tags: go, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Consider the following Go code:

```
type LargeStructWithNestings struct {...}
func generatorChnl() <-chan *LargeStructWithNestings { ... }

// code snippet
chnl := generatorChnl()
for entry := range chnl {    // line A
    doStuffWith(entry)
    entry = nil              // line B
}
```

Assuming that the channel produces values infrequently, and these are pointers to large structs, does `line B` above cause garbage collection of the memory pointed to by `entry` to occur any sooner than it would otherwise do? Or once the loop spins back to `line A`, does the previous location in memory pointed to by `entry` become eligible for garbage collection as soon as the next iteration blocks at `line A`?

The objective is to find a way to keep the resident set size trimmed if possible.

Comment: At what point does the memory pointed to be `entry` become eligible for garbage collection? Only once the next entry is produced / channel is closed? Or immediately at the end of the iteration that produced it?

Comment: The memory is eligible for collection when there is no way to access it. This is more dependent on what `doStuffWith` does in your example. Trying to control GC in this way will get you nowhere in general. If you want to keep memory down, you need to allocate less. You can also try to make the more aggressive with a lower GOGC setting, but that is also going to increase CPU usage and the overall time spent in GC.

Comment: @JimB The question here is on the next iteration: if a value is already stored in `entry`, and receiving another element blocks for a long time, the previous element will be kept in `entry` until the receive can proceed.

Comment: @icza: I see what you mean, but the the same amount would be immediately reallocated in the next iteration, and the runtime is very unlikely to release that memory which is going to be reused anyway.

Comment: @JimB The `entry` is just a pointer, pointing to a large struct. That large struct cannot be gc'ed until a new value is received and assigned to `entry`.

Comment: @icza: yes, I agree that is technically true. What I'm saying that in practice it is unlikely to make much of any difference in the externally visible RSS.

Comment: @JimB Yes, I agree.

Comment: @CppNoob: remember also that garbage collection _does not free memory_ , the job of the garbage collector is to _reuse memory_. Collecting the value slightly sooner does not mean the memory can be released to the OS.

Comment: @JimB but if memory reuse happens earlier, then newer allocations could reuse garbage collected blocks right?

Comment: Technically correct, but in practice there is such a small chance that a significant chunk of the heap memory is always allocated at that exact point, then released with a long enough delay to be collected every single time. You have to be able to handle your peak memory usage, so even one cycle faster than the GC collects it will negate whatever benefit there might have been. We can't tell you for certain what might happen without your actual code, so the only way to actually know is to just try it out, benchmark and profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` statement does not clear the loop variable between iterations. There is a single loop variable which is re-used in each iteration. So until a new value is received from the channel, it will hold the value last assigned to it.

So yes, if receiving from `chnl` blocks for a "long" time, the loop variable `entry` will keep a "reference" to the last received (and assigned) item and thus preventing it from getting garbage collected.

In practice this is rarely–if ever–an issue. Values from channel may be received "frequently", the received values may be "small", there may be other references too, and any combination of these.

If in your specific case this is really an issue, you may clear the variable, but I've never encountered any example where it was needed.